# xargs and zcat: silence errors

Tags: pipe, xargs, signals

Suppose I have:

```
** EDIT TO HAVE CLOSER CORRESPONDENCE TO ACTUAL USAGE **

find ... -regex ... | head -n 1 | xargs -I {} zcat {} | head -n 1
# next, I do some other things
```

now, everything works properly. However, the `xargs -I {} zcat {}` command yields the following error:

```
xargs: zcat: terminated by signal 13
```

Which is something I can ignore for the purposes of what I am trying to do.  However, if I run the code and pipe it into a `less`, the `xargs: zcat: terminated by signal 13` statement is the first line.  This is not desirable. Is there a way to suppress or catch this warning/error-that-is-not-an-error?

Comment: get rid of `ls` and `xargs`: `zcat files/* | head -n 1`.

Comment: If that was meant to print the first line of _each_ file, it wouldn't have worked anyway ;-) Please mention if _that_ was your intention.

Comment: related: [How to make xargs ignore child's exit and keep processing further](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42349/how-to-make-xargs-ignore-childs-exit-and-keep-processing-further). Notice that simply silencing the error message is not a good idea, because xargs will not simply complain, but also STOP right there.

Comment: @mosvy no, it does exactly what is intended.  the `ls` is a placeholder for a long-winded find statement that is out-of-scope.  Bearing in mind that everyone is trying to be helpful here, why is it useful to challenge the scope of the question?

Comment: @mosvy nonetheless, updated the question to be more specific to what is actually happening.

Comment: Because your Q makes no sense. If you really had a problem, describe it precisely.

Comment: @mosvy that is objectively false, I have two clear answers.  Dispute my point (which you can't), or please move on.

Comment: This is not your (or somebody's else) private space. You DO NOT DARE telling people to "move on". Ever again. As it stands, your Q is lousy, and because of that, the existing answers are misleading for other people reading them: ignoring the error message of xargs is NOT the way to go, as explained in my [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577716/xargs-and-zcat-silence-errors#comment1074855_577716) and the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to `zcat` getting a `PIPE` signal sent to it.  This happens because the second time `zcat` is executed (and all other times after that, once for each file except the first), it tries to write across the pipe to `head` after `head` has exited (due to being done with its task of outputting the first line).

You could avoid generating this particular error by reading all data that `zcat` produces.  You can do this by either

```
ls files/* | xargs -I {} zcat {} | { head -n 1; cat >/dev/null; }
```

or

```
ls files/* | xargs -I {} zcat {} | sed -n 1p
```

or

```
ls files/* | xargs -I {} zcat {} | awk 'NR == 1'
```

Or see [Eduardo Trápani's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577718/116858) for how to simply *ignore* the error.

Another way to do this is to only uncompress the first file:

```
set -- files/*
zcat "$1" | head -n 1
```

This does not trigger the `PIPE` signal for `zcat` since it's only executed once, and not for every single file in the directory. This would have the additional benefit that it would cope with any valid filename (e.g. names with embedded newlines).

Comment: so the `xargs -I {} zcat {}` actually follows a `find` expression instrumented out with regular expressions and globbing.  Is that find expression going to be compatible with the `set -- ...` statement you have above?

Comment: @donlan I can not tell. I can only see your `ls` command. But it seems a bit excessive to uncompress _every_ file if you just want the first line from the first file.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you see the message as the first line, it is not being written to the standard output, but to the standard error.

So, this should work:

```
ls files/* | xargs -I {} zcat {} 2>/dev/null | head -n 1
```

It discards the standard error output (sends it to /dev/null)